# MUI Autocomplete with Select All

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using `Material UI (5)` and the `Autocomplete` component with `multiselect` option enabled. I'm also using the "checkbox" customization found in MUI documentation. I'm trying to do a small improvement to be able to **"Check/Uncheck All"** options. To do that, I'm using `PopperComponent` property.

Follow the Code Sandbox example [image]: https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxestags-material-demo-forked-5b0pt

However, I've got 2 problems that I don't know how to solve:

- When I click on Select All -> Click outside the component -> Click again in the component -> Try to click on Select All. Notice that the popup/menu closes... It's like if `ClickAwayListener` intercepts a click outside the component, but it's not true;
- Click in the component -> Scroll Down -> Select an Option -> Notice that the scroll up to the top. It should stay in the same position.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using `ClickAwayListener`, So it considered that 'Select all' `Checkbox` is out of it.

You can prevent that by adding `onMouseDown` event:

```
<Checkbox
    checked={checkAll}
    onChange={checkAllChange}
    id="check-all"
    sx={{ marginRight: "8px" }}
    onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}   // <== add this 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves the first problem. Any clue about the second problem (scroll up to the top when selecting an option)?